# How to load the service API data before canActivate got called

Tags: angular

Hi I am using angular 9 in my application. I am using Auth guard to protect the route from loading. I am checking the application status and DB status before loading my application. If the application or db is down i am routing my application to 'maintenance' route.

1. This is my guard definition:

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import {
          CanActivate,
          ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
          RouterStateSnapshot,
          UrlTree,
          CanActivateChild,
          CanDeactivate
        } from '@angular/router';
        import {Observable, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
        import {DataServiceService} from "./data-service.service";
        import {MaintenanceScreenComponent} from "./maintenance-screen/maintenance-screen.component";
        
        @Injectable({
          providedIn: 'root'
        })
        export class ApplicationStatusGuard implements CanActivate{
          constructor(private data: DataServiceService) {
           data.checkForApplicattionHeath();
          }
        
          message: any;
          subscription: Subscription;
        
          canActivate(
        
              next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
               this.data.currrentStatus.subscribe(response=> this.message= response);
               console.log(this.message);
               return this.message;
        
          }
```

2. This is my DataService

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';
        import {ApiService} from "./services/api.service";
        import {Router} from "@angular/router";
        
        @Injectable({
          providedIn: 'root'
        })
        export class DataServiceService {
          private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
          currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();
        
          private applicationStatus = new BehaviorSubject(null);
          currrentStatus = this.applicationStatus.asObservable();
          res:any;
          constructor(private apiService: ApiService,  private router: Router,) { }
        
          changeMessage(message: string) {
            this.messageSource.next(message)
          }
        
          setAPPlicationStatus(flag) {
            this.applicationStatus.next(flag);
          }
        
          checkForApplicattionHeath(): Observable<boolean> {
        
            const url = 'test';
        
            this.apiService.getMethod(url).subscribe((response:Response) =>{                           //next() callback
                  console.log('response received')
                  this.res = response;
                //  this.checkDbStatus();
                  return this.res;
                },
                (error) => {
                  console.error('Request failed with error ' + error);
                  this.setAPPlicationStatus(false);
                  return false;
                  this.router.navigate(['maintenance']);
        
                });
            return this.res;
          }
        
        }

        Route - { path: 'license', component: LicenseComponent,
                canActivate:[ApplicationStatusGuard]},
```

3. Here the problem is for false cases means application is down it is working fine it is redirecting to maintenance screen. But When application is not down canActivate route is passing first undefined than true. SO how Can i load the data before canActivate got called.

Answer (score 0):

Use another guard before that guard and with an async function check what you want